# Emitting Signals on dbus using Python-dbus

Tags: python, dbus, xfce

I want to be able to at first call a simple script to enable or disable an external monitor from my netbook. I am running Fedora 17 with XFCE as my desktop. I see that I should be able to use python and python-dbus to flip toggle active on and off. My problem is that I can't figure out how to emit a signal to get the new setting to go active. Unfortunately Python is not a language that I use often. The code that I have in place is:

```
import dbus
item = 'org.xfce.Xfconf'
path = '/org/xfce/Xfconf'
channel = 'displays'
base = '/'
setting = '/Default/VGA1/Active'

bus = dbus.SessionBus()
remote_object = bus.get_object(item, path)
remote_interface = dbus.Interface(remote_object, "org.xfce.Xfconf")

if remote_interface.GetProperty(channel, setting):
  remote_interface.SetProperty(channel, setting, '0')
  remote_object.PropertyChanged(channel, setting, '0')
else:
  remote_interface.SetProperty(channel, setting, '1')
  remote_object.PropertyChanged(channel, setting, '0')
```

It is failing and kicking out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./vgaToggle", line 31, in <module>
remote_object.PropertyChanged(channel, setting, '0')   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 140, in __call__
**keywords)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 630, in call_blocking
message, timeout) dbus.exceptions.DBusException: 
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "PropertyChanged"
with signature "sss" on interface "(null)" doesn't exist
```

I spent a bit of time searching and I am not finding many python examples doing anything close to this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`PropertyChanged` is a signal, not a method.  The services you are communicating with are responsible for emitting signals.  In this case, the `PropertyChanged` should fire implicitly, whenever the value of the property on the respective objects or interfaces have changed.

This should happen implicitly when you call `remote_interface.SetProperty(...)`, and you should not need to explicitly "call" the signal like a method.

If you are interested in receiving the signals, you will need to set up a glib main loop and call [connect_to_signal](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html#receiving-signals-from-a-proxy-object) on your proxy object, passing it a callback method to invoke.